# How to push date in the same date

Tags: jquery, html, css, symfony

[image]

I want to loop and push date in 1 date

**example**

```
04-10-2016  1       
04-10-2016  1       
04-10-2016          1
04-10-2016  1       
04-10-2016      1
```

Comment: CAn you explain little more

Comment: Please take a few minutes to review [ask]. There is no way for anyone to understand your issue or help you from this very limited bit of information provided. Also review what a [mcve] is

Comment: this is not a clear question. please provide more details about your question.